# Suppress closing selectbox after choosing option

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu

I'm getting a selectbox with an undefined amount of options.

**Example**
My selectbox contains 50 options with different values. What I do is to just show option 1-10 and 25-30. The others are detached. By clicking option 30 the detached options are attached.

My problem is that the selectbox closes like it always does after a selection. Is there a way to suppress this behaviour?

It would be really great if one clicked option 30 and the detached options would be displayed just under option 30 without the selectbox closing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try setting the select box to be a multiple select box.  Then when the 30th item is selected showing the additional items.

If you are really attached to using a regular select box, then you may be able to produce that action by having a "more options..." `<option>` that , when selected uses javascript to load and reopen the dropdown

If you provide some sample code I could work up an example, maybe

Comment: Hi, thank for your help. Unfortunately the fiddle does not work. How would I reopen a selectbox after selecting an option?

Comment: Did you see the fiddle I made?  With the multi-select box that just "stays" open?  May be the easier way to go about it.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure that the select drop down would be the best element for your requirements.  You may want to consider using a list of checkboxes inside a div whose overflow property is set to scroll.  That might work out better for you. Getting a drop down to do what you've asked is a bit involved. See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7asCW/) for example

Sample html

```
<div id="container">
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="test" value="1" />Option 1</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="test" value="2" />Option 2</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="test" value="3" />Option 3</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="test" value="4" />Option 4</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="test" value="5" />Option 5</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="test" value="6" />Option 6</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="test" value="7" />Option 7</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="test" value="8" />Option 8</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="test" value="9" />Option 9</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="test" value="10" />Option 10</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="test" value="11" />Option 11</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="test" value="12" />Option 12</label>
</div>
```

The CSS

```
label{display:block;}
#container{height:100px;width:200px;overflow:scroll;}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for sharing your thoughts. The user however should be able to select one option only as it will be a selection box filled with years.

Comment: You can modify the solution to be radio buttons so that would guarantee one option selected at a time. Or you can use JS to modify checkboxes behavior to allow one option only. However, the latter approach would require validation on your part on the server side to ensure that this is the case. Otherwise, if a user has JS disabled, you'd lose that check